# Sending a message to a server to be broadcasted to a user

Tags: notifications, websocket

Sorry if this question has been asked before but it's specific(i think).

I have this system that allows you to place an order in a market. What i would like to do is to inform both parties through notification, like a popup screen will appear at the side:

The structure is:
Buyer => makes order => check with Database => Notify Seller => Seller

My question is to do this, what should i look into (Socket IO? or web sockets?)? And do i need a server? So far i've been coding in jquery javascript, php and mysql for database.

Thanks in advance for any help rendered. Would be nice to provide a site link to point me in the right direction as well :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket IO is not possible, if it is web based app, unless you are OK with plugins. You could certainly have a look at WebSockets, but it needs HTML5 browsers at both the ends. 
Otherwise, you can try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming),

In any case, you need relevant support from Server.